# How do Refresh token api call and continue the apis in Retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, interceptor

I have to implement Retrofit2 for api calls. And while trying to implement interceptor for perform refresh token api call and proceed current api cals,
We cannot perform the authtoken failed check since the response is as given below

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Token needs refresh",
    "mode": "dev",
    "needs_refresh": true,
    "statusCode": 400,
    "success": false,
    "url": "/transactions"
}
```

How can we handle this response in interceptor and do a refresh token api call.

This is how my interceptor look like. I want to check the key "needs_refresh" to perform the getNewToken()

```html
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain?): Response {
        var request = chain!!.request()
        var response = chain.proceed(request)

        if(response.code()==400) {

           getNewToken()
        }
        val token: String = MyApp.prefs[PrefConstants.KEY_PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN,""]
        if(!token.isEmpty())
        request = request?.newBuilder()
                ?.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                ?.build()
        else
            request = request?.newBuilder()
                    ?.build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
```

Comment: you can get statuscode in reponse .

Comment: Make sure your getNewToken() method has has retrofit call with execute() not for enqueue() ?

Comment: sure my getNewtoken() using the same idea. but My problem is to identify from error whether we need to perform the getNewToken or not. I want to check "needs_refresh" key for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one model class for your response as below.

```
public class ResponseModel{

@SerializedName("mode")
private String mode;

@SerializedName("needs_refresh")
private boolean needsRefresh;

@SerializedName("error_description")
private String errorDescription;

@SerializedName("success")
private boolean success;

@SerializedName("error")
private String error;

@SerializedName("url")
private String url;

@SerializedName("statusCode")
private int statusCode;

public void setMode(String mode){
    this.mode = mode;
}

public String getMode(){
    return mode;
}

public void setNeedsRefresh(boolean needsRefresh){
    this.needsRefresh = needsRefresh;
}

public boolean isNeedsRefresh(){
    return needsRefresh;
}

public void setErrorDescription(String errorDescription){
    this.errorDescription = errorDescription;
}

public String getErrorDescription(){
    return errorDescription;
}

public void setSuccess(boolean success){
    this.success = success;
}

public boolean isSuccess(){
    return success;
}

public void setError(String error){
    this.error = error;
}

public String getError(){
    return error;
}

public void setUrl(String url){
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUrl(){
    return url;
}

public void setStatusCode(int statusCode){
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public int getStatusCode(){
    return statusCode;
}
```

}

Updated your intercept

```html
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain?): Response {
        
        var request = chain!!.request()
        var response = chain.proceed(request)

        var responseModel = ResponseModel()
        var gson = Gson();
       

        if(response.getCode() == 400) {
 responseModel = gson.fromJson(response.body()?.string(), ResponseModel::class.java);
if(responseModel.isNeedsRefresh()){
            getNewToken()
}
        }
        val token: String = MyApp.prefs[PrefConstants.KEY_PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN,""]
        if(!token.isEmpty())
        request = request?.newBuilder()
                ?.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                ?.build()
        else
            request = request?.newBuilder()
                    ?.build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
```

Comment: Yes this is a good idea, but I didn't get the json from response.body().toString()

Comment: what are you getting in response.body().toString() ?

Comment: Its object name. But, now I got the answer we have to use Try to use body().string() instead of body().toString(), U please change it, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use okhttp along with retrofit,

```
class NetworkInterceptor @Inject constructor(val context: Context) : Interceptor {

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        var response = request.proceed(request)
        if(response?.code()==400){
            //you can refresh your token here and chain your calls 
         }
     return response;
   }
}
```

Comment: But the 400 is also coming for login credential error or on some other apis. I want to distinguish this by checking the "needs_refresh" key in the error response

Comment: Then you have a messy API that returns 400 whatever. Anyway, this snippet exposes `response` from which you can even read the body I believe. Implement your own logic where Rajat Beck placed a comment. This is a good answer.